# Declare a pointer to an integer at address 0x200 in memory

Tags: c, memory, pointers

I have a couple of doubts, I remember some where that it is not possible for me to manually put a variable in a particular location in memory, but then I came across this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int *x;
x=0x200;
printf("Number is %lu",x); // Checkpoint1
scanf("%d",x);
printf("%d",*x);
}
```

Is it that we can not put it in a particular location, or we should not put it in a particular location since we will not know if it's a valid location or not?

Also, in this code, till the first checkopoint, I get output to be 512. 
And then after that Seg Fault.

Can someone explain why? Is 0x200 not a valid memory location?

Comment: As written, this is not even valid C. Integers do not implicitly convert to pointers; you need a cast. But more fundamentally, you can't just assume a random address corresponds to memory you could store something at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case - **the behavior you will get is undefined** - everything can happen.

In linux for example, the first 1GB is reserved for kernel, so if you try to access it - you will get a seg fault because you are trying to access a kernel memory in user mode.

No idea how it works in windows.

---

[Reference for linux claim](http://linux-mm.org/HighMemory):

> Currently the 32 bit x86 architecture is the most popular type of
>   computer. In this architecture, traditionally the Linux kernel has
>   split the 4GB of virtual memory address space into 3GB for user
>   programs and 1GB for the kernel.

Comment: It's the last 1GB, not the first 1GB, that's reserved for the kernel. However in the default configuration Linux forbids creation of maps below a certain address; mapping of memory at or near page 0 is dangerous because it interferes with null pointer traps in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @amit wrote:

In windows it is the same. In general it is the same for all protected-mode operating systems. Since DOS etc. are no longer around it is the same with all systems except kernel-mode (km-drivers) and embedded systems.

The operating system manages which memory-pages you are allowed to write to and places markers that will make the cpu automatically raise access-violations if some other page is written to.

Answer (score 0):

Up until the "checkpoint", you haven't accessed memory location 0x200, so everything works fine.

There I'd a local variable `x` in the function `main`. It is of type "pointer to int". `x` is assigned the value 0x200, and then that value is printed. But the *target* of x hasn't been accessed, so up to this point it doesn't matter whether `x` holds a valid memory address or not.

Then `scanf` tries to write to the memory address you passed in, which is the 0x200 stored in `x`. Then you get a seg fault, which is certainly sac possible result of trying to write to an arbitrary memory address.

So what are your doubts? What makes you think that this might work, when you come across this code that clearly doesn't?

Writing to a particular memory address *might* work under certain conditions, but is extremely unlikely to in general. Under all modern OSes, normal programs do not have control over their memory layout. The OS decides where initial things like the program's code, stack, and globals go. The OS will probably also be using some memory space, and it is not required to tell you what it's using. Instead you ask for memory (either by making variables or by calling memory allocation routines), and you use that.

So writing to particular addresses is very very likely to get either memory that hasn't been allocated, or memory that is being used for some other purpose. Neither of those is good, even if you do manage to hit an address that is actually writable. What if you clobber sundry some piece of data used by one of your program's other variables? Or some other part of your program clobbers the value you just wrote?

You should never be choosing a particular hard-coded memory address, you should be using an address of something you know is a variable, or an address you got from something like `malloc`.